# php получить результат и 1 запроса и использовать его во втором

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите в чем косяк... в пхп не силен.
Нужно получить результат из 1 запроса и вставить во второй.

```
if ($_POST['data']) {
    $id_data = $_POST['data'];
    $get_data = $db->query( "select data_p from " . USERPREFIX . "_zapis where id=$id_data" );
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($get_data);
        echo($row[0]);

    $db->query( "select id, time_p from " . USERPREFIX . "_zapis where data_p='".$row[0]."'" );
```

Comment: это `PDO` у вас  или что? `$row = $get_data->fetch()`. Вы лучше бы переписали это все одним запросом.

Comment: Точно, что то я туплю) Спасибо сделал. Это cms dle.